# How to properly create thousands of cypher nodes over the neo4j REST API?

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher, node-async

I need to create a lot (say 50.000) of nodes via node.js in cypher < 3.0.0. I am using a async.times to post all cypher queries. However it seems that the REST API is chocking (and dies) because there are probably too many requests coming through. I would like to keep using node instead of using LOAD CSV. My code is below:

```
var createStyles = function (data, cb)
{
    var distinctData = ...;
    console.log("creating styles"); 
    ...

    var create = function (id, callback)
    {
        console.log("creating st " + id); 
        var req = ...
        styles.addOrUpdate(req, null,
            function (err, node)
            {
                callback(null, node);
            });
    }
    // call the same function multiple times with a different index
    async.times(distinctData.length - 1, function (n, next)
    {
        create(n, function (err, st)
        {
            next(err, st)
        })
    }, function (err, result)
    {
        console.log("styles created");
        createdStyles = result;
        cb(null, result);
    });
};
```

The addOrUpdate function looks like this:

```
exports.addOrUpdate = function (req, res, cb)
{
    if (req.body.styleName === undefined) req.body.styleName = "N/A";
    if (req.body.description === undefined) req.body.description = "";
    if (req.body.price === undefined) req.body.price = 0;

    var styleName = req.body.styleName.replace(/\\/g,"\\\\").replace(/'/g, "\\'");
    var styleNum = req.body.styleNum.toString().replace(/'/g, "").replace(/\\/g,"");
    var desc = req.body.description.replace(/'/g, "").replace(/\\/g,"");

    var dts = dateHelper.getDTS();
    var styleID = uuid.v4();
    if (req.body.styleID !== undefined && req.body.styleID != "") styleID = req.body.styleID;

    var query = "" +
        "    MATCH (c:Customer {customerID: '" + req.body.customerID + "'}) " +
        "    MATCH (c)<-[r:DEPT_OF]-(dept:Dept {deptID: '" + req.body.departmentID + "'}) " +
        "    MATCH (dept)<-[r1:IN_DEPT]-(pt:ProductType {productTypeID: '" + req.body.productTypeID + "'}) " +
        "    MERGE (st:Style {styleNum: '" + styleNum + "'}) " +
        "    ON MATCH " +
        "    SET " +
        "       st.styleNum = '" + styleNum + "', " +
        "       st.name = '" + styleName + "', " +
        "       st.desc = '" + desc + "', " +
        "       st.price = " + req.body.price + ", " +
        "       st.modifiedDTS = " + dts +
        "    ON CREATE " +
        "    SET " +
        "       st.styleID = '" + styleID + "', " +
        "       st.styleNum = '" + styleNum + "', " +
        "       st.name = '" + styleName + "', " +
        "       st.desc = '" + desc + "', " +
        "       st.price = " + req.body.price + ", " +
        "       st.modifiedDTS = " + dts + ", " +
        "       st.createdDTS = " + dts + " " +
        "    WITH pt, st " +
        "    MERGE (pt)<-[r2:OF_TYPE]-(st) " +
        "    return st;";

    console.log(query);     
    db.cypherQuery(query, function (err, node)
    {
        if (err)
        {
            return cb(err, node);
        }
        else
        {
            cb(err, node.data[0]);
        }
    });
};
```

Is there anything I can do to make this work without choking neo4j?

Comment: As I mentioned on Slack, you may find LOAD CSV to be faster, and it works with URIs for the input source.

Comment: Thanks @JohnKaster. I tried it and its a lot faster. Will try to implement that with node.js.

Comment: Glad it helps, @skone!

Answer (score 2):

1. Use Parameters
2. use async.series
3. why do you do ON MATCH SET ?
4. make sure you have all indexes / constrraints in place (e.g. Customer {customerID} )
5. Neo4j < 3.0 uses the RULE planner for updates which might not perform as well on complex update queries,

so yo could split your query into one that does the matching, and just returns the id's of: `pt` and passes that then to the update query which does the merge and the by-id lookup of the product type

6. use PROFILE / EXPLAIN with your query to see if they are actually performing well for highly concurrent load
7. consider batching queries e.g. 10k to 100k updates in one transaction

Comment: Thanks. Although all of these suggestions are great. I am going to use LoadCSV for now. I thought I could get it reasonable working fast, however I don't think I will be able to beat LoadCSV.